# Who is the manufacturer of the power inverter used by Ampaire electric aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-systems, electrical-system, electric-engine, electric-aircraft

Please see the picture within this [**article**](https://www.ainonline.com/aviation-news/air-transport/2021-08-31/electric-power-may-transform-regional-airline-business-models).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a device from Cascadia, Unitek, Sevcon, or Emsiso.

The motor looks like an Emrax axial flux motor. At one point, Emrax's [user guide](https://emrax.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/manual_for_emrax_motors_version_5.4.pdf) said their motors are compatible with controllers from the four manufacturers I listed above. Now, the user guide just links to a broken URL.

Cascadia used to be Rinehart Motion Systems. Cascadia's controllers are more expensive, but their documentation and support is **excellent**. I would *highly* recommend their systems.